PyQt6 PlotWidget - how to adjust two-row plot title?
I am making an app in PyQt6 and one step of it is to create a plot. Here is a part of the code responsible for it:
plot_widget = PlotWidget()
            plot_widget.setFixedSize(600, 400)
            plot_widget.setBackground('w')
            title = f"""<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 12pt; width: 100%;">{window.chosen_customer} - {window.chosen_product} <br> {prop}</div>"""
            plot_item = plot_widget.getPlotItem()
            plot_item.setContentsMargins(15, 15, 10, 10)
            plot_item.setTitle(title)

However, as a result  I obtain centered title, adjusted to left side:

I want the "Sieb 63 um" to also be centered, not on the left. How can I obtain this?
I tried with different configurations of HTML, but nothing works. I guess, even though there is a <br>, the whole text is still recognized as one, but I don't know how to fix it.

This question is similar to: QGraphicsTextItem Setting Text Width For Text Centring. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The title label uses QGraphicsTextItem, so, as the documentation explains, in order to properly center the text, you either call setTextWidth() or adjustSize(): add plot_item.titleLabel.item.adjustSize() after setting the title text.
